# How can I replace query results less than a certain length with NULL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following statements in my `SELECT` query that properly formats phone numbers that were not validated correctly in the database...it's ugly, but it works:

```
COALESCE(
               SUBSTRING(STUFF(STUFF(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(OFFICE_PHONE,'-',' '),',',' '),' ',''), '(', ''), ')', ''),
  4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'), 1, 12),
               SUBSTRING(STUFF(STUFF(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MOBILE_PHONE,'-',' '),',',' '),' ',''), '(', ''), ')', ''),
  4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'), 1, 12),
               SUBSTRING(STUFF(STUFF(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FIELD_PHONE,'-',' '),',',' '),' ',''), '(', ''), ')', ''),
  4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'), 1, 12)) AS ValidPhoneNumber,
```

This query removes any "**bad**" characters and makes sure a number looks like: `123-456-7890`

However, there are a few entries that are less than 12 characters; like `123-983-12`....

How can I replace entries less than 12 characters in length with `NULL`?

Thanks!

Comment: [`LEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Larnu is there anything other than LEN?  I did try that..I put `LEN(` in front of all 3 lines and it just returns 12 for every phone number.  So I don't think LEN will work in my case.

Comment: Have you considered using a `CASE` expression?

Comment: If you have a fixed length datatype the value from LEN will always be the same for every row. In that case you would either need to use TRIM or DATALENGTH.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks! Will your case statement return NULL if the number is less than 12?  thanks again

Comment: @SeanLange what do you mean by this, it sounds like your saying that something like `SELECT LEN(CONVERT(char(10),'abc'));` would return `10` not `3`, while `SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(char(10),'abc'));` would return `3`. It's the other way around.

Comment: Oh dear.....just reading this and yes I typed that backwards. Thanks for pointing out my gaff @Larnu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear that you will have to repeat the ugly expressions like this:

```sql
CASE WHEN LEN(ugly_expression) >= 12 THEN ugly_expression END
```

Unless you make a stored function (with [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))  for the phone number sanitizer.

```sql
COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN LEN( dbo.SanitizePhone(OFFICE_PHONE) ) >= 12
    THEN dbo.SanitizePhone(OFFICE_PHONE) END,
    CASE WHEN LEN( dbo.SanitizePhone(MOBILE_PHONE) ) >= 12
    THEN dbo.SanitizePhone(MOBILE_PHONE) END,
    CASE WHEN LEN( dbo.SanitizePhone(FIELD_PHONE) ) >= 12
    THEN dbo.SanitizePhone(FIELD_PHONE) END
) AS ValidPhoneNumber
```

Note that if there is no ELSE case in the CASE expression and the THEN case does not apply, NULL will be returned automatically.

See: [SQL CASE Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

---

You could also get the sanitized phone numbers in a sub-select

```sql
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN LEN(phone1) >= 12 THEN phone1 END,
    CASE WHEN LEN(phone2) >= 12 THEN phone2 END,
    CASE WHEN LEN(phone3) >= 12 THEN phone3 END
  ) AS ValidPhoneNumber,
  ...
FROM (
    SELECT
      STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(...OFFICE_PHONE...))) AS phone1,
      STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(...MOBILE_PHONE...))) AS phone2,
      STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(...FIELD_PHONE...))) AS phone3,
      ...
    FROM ...
) phones
```

Comment: thanks, what is SanitizePhone?

Comment: A supposed user defined stored function doing the phone number simplification. See [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: *If* you want a user defined function, @OlivierJacot-Descombes , you need to schema qualify it.